# C# Search for first number in integer/string

Tags: c#, string, winforms, integer

I have a textbox where people have to enter a number but I don't want to them to type the number 0 in first, how do I do this?

Example: If they type, 10 it's ok but if they type 010 it's not ok and I want a window to appear and tell them to try again.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about Windows Forms, WPF or any other UI framework? Please use the relevant tag.

Comment: ok - so what have you tried?

Comment: And moreover please show your affords, in particular your code.

Comment: Yes windows forms

Comment: `bool ok = text.Length > 0 && text[0] != (char)0x30;` ?

Comment: Do you want to stop them, or is it acceptable to simply remove the invalid character? i.e. `text = text.TrimStart('0');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `TextChanged` event. (Double click on the event in the properties of the textbox in the designer)   In this example trim any leading spaces before comparison and remove the character if it is a `0`

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string input = textBox1.Text.TrimStart(' ');
    if (input.Length == 1)
    {
        textBox1.Text = input == "0" ? "" : input;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

As pointed out by m.rogalski and Roma the version above allows for entering the 0 after the input of a valid character. This version bellow will correct this mistake:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.TrimStart('0');
}
```

Comment: This is only checking if input is 1 sign long meaning that it wont catch first `0` in `010`

Comment: @m.rogalski not quite. It is only acting on the first real character. It will not allow you to put a `0` as the first character

Comment: @MongZhu, but you can firstly type `1` and then type `0` before `1` and it will fail

Comment: You can copy and paste the text into this box  in which case your method will fail. Another fail will be if someone inserts `1` then `0` then `1` and then removes first `1` making the full text `01` which is 2 signs long.

Comment: @m.rogalski you are right. made a correction in my post. Thank you

Comment: @Roma you are right. made a correction in my post. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Add `TextChanged` handler to your textbox (in your form find event for TextBox and type this name: `TextBox_TextChanged`):

```
void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = sender as TextBox;

    if (textBox != null)
    {
        textBox.Text = textBox.Text.Trim();

        if (textBox.Text.Length > 0 && textBox.Text[0] == '0')
        {
            textBox.Text = textBox.Text.TrimStart('0');
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect value");
        }                
    }
}
```

Or in code:

```
TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
textBox.TextChanged += TextBox_TextChanged;
```

Comment: This can produce `NullReferenceException` when sender is not a `TextBox`

Comment: e.Handled = true;

the handles comes up red

Comment: There is no `Handled` property in basic `EventArgs`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
private void MyTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
    var textBox = sender as TextBox;   
    if (textBox.Text.StartsWith("0"))      
        //alert user      
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid starting character");      
}
```

Of course you need to bind TextChanged event in designer or in code like this:

```
MyTextBox.TextChanged += MyTextBox_TextChanged;
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the beginnign :

> If they type, 10 it's ok but if they type 010 it's not ok

If it's okay for user to type integer ranging from `0` to `infinity` then you can use this :

```
if(textBox.Text.Length > 1 && textBox.Text[0] == '0')
```

This assumes that user can type '0' as a first sign only if it is only sign. If that's not what you wanted then change it to this :

```
if(textBox.Text.Length > 0 && textBox.Text[0] == '0')
```

Going further :

> I want a window to appear and tell them to try again

You can just show `MessageBox` and clear text inside `textBox` :

```
textBox.Text = string.Empty;
MessageBox.Show("Value entered is incorrect. Please try again");
```

Then combining these you'll have something like :

```
if(textBox.Text.Length > 1/* or 0 depending on what you need */ && textBox.Text[0] == '0')
{
    textBox.Text = string.Empty;
    MessageBox.Show("Value entered is incorrect. Please try again");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put this code to after Initialize method

```
textBox1.TextChanged = (s, o) =>
{
    if (textBox1.Text.StartsWith("0"))
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Remove(0, 1);
        MessageBox.Show("Cant start with '0'");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could have a ViewModel representing some textboxes, one of which is your "Number" textbox. Then you can use an attribute on your Number property to make sure it is validated.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
   ...

    [Required]
    [NumberValidation]
    string NumberTextBox {get;set;}
```

where NumberValidation is another public class implementing a ValidationAttribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property]
public class NumberValidation : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value.StartsWith("0"))
        {
                return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage, "Please enter another number!");
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```